# cocos2d CCSprite not getting coordinates 

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4

**SOLVED!**

**to get coordinates of the sprites frame use sprite.boundingBox.origin.x;**

Hello!
I am implementing a simple code but I cannot understand its behavior:

```
anewSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grossini.png"];
anewSprite.position = ccp(80, 80);
[self addChild:anewSprite];


anotherSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"grossini.png"];
anotherSprite.position = ccp(300, 80);
[self addChild:anotherSprite];



-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];

    NSLog(@"point x:%f y:%f", point.x, point.y);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(anewSprite.textureRect, point)){
        NSLog(@"contains point");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"does not contain");
    }
    return  TRUE;
}



-(void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint point= [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];

    anewSprite.position = point;
    if (CGRectContainsRect(anewSprite.textureRect, anotherSprite.textureRect) == TRUE) {
        NSLog(@"Intersects");
    }
}
```

The problem is following:

`NSLog(@"anotherSpriteTextureRectOrigin X:%f Y:%f", enemy1.textureRect.origin.x, enemy1.textureRect.origin.y);` 
`NSLog(@"anewSpriteTextureRectOrigin X:%f Y:%f", anewSprite.textureRect.origin.x, anewSprite.textureRect.origin.y);`

shows: 
anotherSpriteTextureRectOrigin X:0.000000 Y:0.000000 
anewSpriteTextureRectOrigin X:0.000000 Y:0.000000

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not write "SOLVED" in the title. That job is done by the "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To check, whether one sprite intersects/contains another, instead of sprite.frame.rect use sprite.boundingBox**

Eg:

```
if (CGRectContainsRect(sprite1.boundingBox, sprite2.boundingBox)) {
     NSLog(@"Contains");
}
```